# Algorithm to select pet breed / cars / bikes / etc from database based on user answers

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, algorithm, search

This quesiton is more about getting a point in the right direction. I inherited and developed upon a project to create a car selection database (matching user preferences). It is already working relatively well but could be better (there are a few issues), so I'd like to study some other algorithms used by others. The site I'm working on uses a best match algorithm where each car is assigned a "1" each time it matches a quesiton answered and these are added up.

I like in particular, the following site (to select dog breeds):

http://animal.discovery.com/breed-selector/dog-breeds.html

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to where I might find something similar (I've been looking, but probably not looking in the right places or using the right search terms)? I'd like to be able to view and study the algorithm used (PHP/mySQL).

The (incomplete) site I'm working on:

http://www.myperfectcar.com.ph/

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: please remove animated background before i have a fit and and fall off my chair.

Comment: what is the algorithm currently used? is it like "+1 for relatedness to item" or is there a "like-ness algoritm" like the distance calculation?

Comment: @Dagon - yah, I hate the animated background and get dizzy each time I look at it, but sometimes, the developer doesn't have the last say.

Comment: @Joseph - it's +1 for relatedness.

Comment: tell the customer that causing users to have seizures when visiting their web site is not a good look (and illegal in some places)

Answer (score 0):

It is exactly as any other filter with dropdowns, except that it is implemented in wizard-like form. You need to have some class, in session with more-less such structure:

```
public class CarSearchWizard
{
    public int Passengiers = 0;
    public int DrivingFor = 0;
    ...
}
```

I didn't notice that your search depends on previous selection, so it is rather simple - filter for number of people, driving etc on each iteration of user search. I think your algorythm is ok, except it is rather long to fulfill :)

Comment: You are right mr A. Your comments are exactly why I'm looking for additional info. There is no filter on each iteration and it is a little simplistic. I had thought about the hard filter (as in your comment), but I guess I'm looking for a cross between that and what we currently have ... is that possible??? I figured if I can see what else is out there, I can work out how much of our algorithm I need to change and if the database structure needs to be edited (and hence the CMS as well - hope not!).

Comment: I've never worked with "like-ness algorythm". But as far as I concerned, almost everything could be made discrete